# Error al utilizar propiedad onPress en React native

Tags: react-native, expo

Estoy tratando de utilizar de la propiedad Onpress en un TouchableOpacity, sin embargo, cuando lo pruebo me tira el siguiente error.

NativeAnimatedModule.startOperationBatch() is not a function.(in 'NativeAnimatedModule.startOperationBatch()','NativeAnimatedModulestartOperationBatch' is undefined)

Estoy trabajando con expo, no tengo ni idea de a qué se debe este error ya que solo estoy utilizando una simple función del mismo TouchableOpacity, y creo estar ejecutando mi propia función de manera correcta, espero que alguien pueda colaborarme

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import {View,TouchableOpacity,Text,StyleSheet,Image,PixelRatio} from 'react-native'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import * as Font from 'expo-font'
import Logo from '../assets/logo.jpg';
const Login=()=>{
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const  [fontsLoaded,setFontsLoaded]=useState(false);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(!fontsLoaded){
            loadFonts();
        }
    },[])
    const loadFonts=async()=>{
        await Font.loadAsync({
            'BungeeRegular': require('../assets/fonts/Bungee-Regular.ttf')
        })
        setFontsLoaded(true);
    }
    if(!fontsLoaded){
        return(<View/>)
    }
    const test=()=>{
        console.log("hola")
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image source={Logo} style={styles.logo}/>
            <Text style={styles.mesadokoText}>MESADOKO</Text>
            <Text style={styles.TextLogo}>Have fun while you learn for free</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.signButton} onPress={test}><Text style={styles.signButtonText} activeOpacity={0.9}>SIGN IN</Text></TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>───You don’t have an account yet?───</Text>
            <Text style={styles.signButtonText}>SIGN UP</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center'
    },
    logo:{
        marginTop:5,
        width:338/PixelRatio.get(),
        height:310/PixelRatio.get()
    },
    TextLogo:{
        color:'#5B5B5B',
        marginTop:0,
        marginBottom:70,//288
        fontSize:16,
        
    },
    mesadokoText:{
        color:'#F28705',
        marginTop:20,
        fontSize:30,
        fontFamily:'BungeeRegular'
        
    },  
    signButton:{
        //borderRadius:15,
        //height:60,
        //width: 300, //980px redimensioné a 550 para que se pudiera visualizar correctamente en android
        //borderWidth: 2.5,
        //borderColor: '#F28705',
        //alignItems:'center',
        //justifyContent:"center",
        //marginBottom:80,
        //backgroundColor:'white'
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems:'center',
        borderColor: '#F28705',
        borderWidth: 2.5,
        padding: 10,
        height: 60,
        width: 300,
        borderRadius: 10,
        marginBottom:80,
        elevation: 10,
        shadowRadius: 10,
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.6,
        shadowColor: 'black',
    },
    signButtonText:{
        color:'#F28705',
        fontSize:20,
        
    },
    buttonText:{
        color:'#5B5B5B',
        fontSize:17,
        marginBottom:15
    },
})
export default Login;
```

Comment: Parece el modulo encargado de la animacion no  existe, create un poyecto nuevo con expo y fijate si sale el mismo error, obvio no toques nada solo pon un touc opacity y prueba

Comment: Al parecer mi proyecto tuvo unos errores al crearse y algunos archivos se corrompieron, la solución es volver a crear el proyecto con expo, instalar todas las dependencias y volver a colocar toda la carpeta del código fuente

Answer (score 0):

La causa de este error fue un fallo al crear mi proyecto con expo, para solucionarlo tuve que crear de nuevo el proyecto, instalar las dependencias que quería utilizar y pegar mi carpeta de src, no es muy común que pase esto pero no significa que no pueda ocurrir en algún momento de la vida.